# Reusing Java classes with procedural-style code?

Tags: oop, jakarta-ee, java-7

There's a solid chance I'm misusing classes here which is why I need your help.

I've started developing with Java EE and one of the problems I am facing is I have a process which I have organised in a class, call it: "SendEmail.java".

Now let's say I have two other classes called "Thunderalert.java" and "FloodAlert.java" which will use all the methods that SendEmails.java has within it.

So I want to know the best way of using the SendEmails methods from each of the other classes.

- Should I be creating an instance of SendEmails and accessing each method individually and error checking along the way (what if an exception is thrown?).. It's methods are just procedural code, so it's not really an 'object' as such
- Shall I just be using the one method that runs all the other internal ones from within SendMail
- Should this SendMail be redesigned as a helper class-type design?

I'm still quite new at Java EE so I'm not sure if there are any options available which I am missing

Comment: Hard to tell without seeing code, but it seems that client code should only need to call a single method to get an email sent (and not have to worry about a sequence of "internal ones").

Comment: From how you've described it, `ThunderAlert` and `FloodAlert` should both extend an `Alert` class, and the `Alert` class should have all the implementation for `SendEmail`. `ThunderAlert` and `FloodAlert` would only provide information regarding their specific behavior, i.e. a thunder-based message that takes into account distance, and a flood alert that takes into account water height.

Comment: Why not using JavaMail Api?

Answer (score 1):

I think you should have one public method inside `SendEmail` class. 
Btw, I would consider changing its name. I think having method `send()` when class is called `SendEmail` is not the best way (not to mention about names like `call()`, `invoke()` etc).

This is [great article](http://steve-yegge.blogspot.com/2006/03/execution-in-kingdom-of-nouns.html) about this problem (The Kingdom of Nouns) in java.

What about something like: `new Email(recipient, body).send()`?

Or if you want to do it in a service style, I'd call it for example `MailService`

Comment: +1, but i would say a note, a clean design should envolves more classes, send method in `Email` will use SMTP or IMAP (with some extensions)?? another thing, an Email can't send itself, instead a protocol client can send emails, `MailService` can send/read/delete emails, this question needs more invistigation from the OP using OOD techniques :)

Comment: I agree. It needs to use Java Mail API somehow. We could create class called `Postman` with all low level mechanism inside and use it like this: `postman.send(new Email(recipient, body))`. I think appropriate names are very important but sometimes hard to design the way they contains expected behaviour.